# Exclude draft articles from Solr index with Sunspot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, sunspot

I have an indexed model called Article and I don't want solr to index unpublished articles.

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
    text :title
    text :body
  end
end
```

How can I specify that article that is not #published? should not be indexed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Be sure to index the published status.

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
    text :title
    text :body
    boolean :is_published, :using => :published?
  end
end
```

Then add a filter to your query

```
Sunspot.search(Article) do |search|
  search.with(:is_published, true)
  # ...
end
```

Comment: In our case that will extend Solr index twice because most the articles stay drafts forever in our database. So this solution is not acceptable for us.

Comment: Hi Simone. Let say an Article belongs_to a Category, and a (whole) category can be published. How do you search some articles filtered by categories published?

Comment: @Fro_oo I encourage you to open a new question

Comment: You're right :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574173/how-to-restrict-sunspot-search-with-nested-attributes

Comment: Hmmm, this approach is not super safe, though. I'd rather be able to exclude some records from being indexed at indexing time. This way, no matter in how many places in the code I search the model, I know there's no chance I'll forget to exclude unwanted instances.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to make sure unpublished articles are *never* included in the search index, you can do it this way instead:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable :if => :published? do
     text :title
     text :body
  end
end
```

The model will then only be indexed when published.

My approach is less interesting if you also want admins to be able to search for articles, including unpublished ones, however.

Note: calling `article.index!` will add the instance to the index regardless of the `:if => :method` param.

Answer (score 3):

A small look into the code base of sunspot_rails reveals a method called `maybe_mark_for_auto_indexing` which will be added to the models that include solr. You could override that method and set `@marked_for_auto_indexing` based on your criteria in the specific model. Its monkey patching but can help you solve the problem. The code for ur reference is in `lib/sunspot/searchable.rb`.