# Rails - Sunspot conditional model indexing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, lucene, full-text-search, sunspot, sunspot-rails

Is there any way to determine on runtime if a model should be indexed or not? Something like:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

  searchable :if => :indexable? do 
    ...
  end

  private
  def indexable?
    ...
  end

end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answered here

[Exclude draft articles from Solr index with Sunspot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730295/exclude-draft-articles-from-solr-index-with-sunspot)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good article on conditional indexing: http://mikepackdev.com/blog_posts/19-conditional-indexing-with-sunspot

That is, exactly the API you propose in your question.