# How to restrict Sunspot search with nested models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, solr, sunspot

I want to filter the Sunspot search results with `with(:is_available, true)`.
This is working with the `User` model, but I can't make it work with the `Itinerary` model.

app/controllers/search_controller.rb:

```ruby
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :fulltext_actions
  private
    def fulltext_actions
      @itineraries = do_fulltext_search(Itinerary)
      @users = do_fulltext_search(User)
      @itineraries_size = @itineraries.size
      @users_size = @users.size
    end
    def do_fulltext_search(model)
      Sunspot.search(model) do
        with(:is_available, true)
        fulltext params[:search]
      end.results
    end
end
```

app/models/user.rb:

```ruby
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :itineraries, :dependent => :destroy
  searchable do
    text :first_name, :boost => 3
    text :last_name, :boost => 3
    text :status
    boolean :is_available, :using => :available?
  end
  def available?
    !self.suspended
  end
end
```

app/models/itinerary.rb:

```ruby
class Itinerary < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  searchable do
    text :title, :boost => 3
    text :budget
    text :description
    boolean :is_available, :using => :available?
  end
  def available?
    !self.user.suspended
  end
end
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, my real problem was the indexation.

When I update the `User` model, I set a flag (like `user_instance.update_index_flag = true`) in my controller.

In the `User` model:

```
attr_accessor :update_index_flag
after_save :reindex_sunspot
def reindex_sunspot
  if self.update_index_flag
    Sunspot.index(self.itineraries.to_a)
  end
end
```

That's it...

Comment: What's up with the no-op `inject` statement? Are you just looking for a `to_a` there?