# Search using Sunspot:solr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot-rails

I have two models, named as Products and Variants, in which Variant model have association 
with Products as a Product have many Variants. Variant model have field named as 
"available_on" ... I want to implement search using two dates as check-in n checkout dates.

.

if variants for a product available for each date , check-in date to checkout date, result will map all those products and it is the result....

.
.
guide me how i should give conditions using Sunspot:solr

roughly my models are like this

```
product
{
product_id integer
has_many variants
}

variant
{
variant_id integer
available_on date
belongs_to product
}
```

check-in n checkout are the inputs for the search.

Comment: i guess you can find answer - [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730295/exclude-draft-articles-from-solr-index-with-sunspot

Comment: this link specifies simple search for one model, I have asked for two or more models having associations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it will be easier to answer if you put your models in question but in general way if you have has_many relationship than you should index nested model

```
#variant model

searchable do

  integer :product_id
  time :check_in     
  time :check_out     

end
```

if you need to index something from parent `has_many` model you can use `:multiple=>true` option in this way

```
#product model

def variant_ids     
  variants.collect(&:id)
end

searchable do

  integer :variant_ids, :multiple=>true
  ...

end
```

Comment: I have added models roughly, I got How to make searchable, now how to put condition for search?

Comment: provide example of condition you want to implement

Comment: I want to search for products who are available for checking date to checkout date, means for each date that product have a variant. for example If I input 2013-01-24 in check-in and 2013-01-26 as checkout date, then results will show the products having variants for date 24, 25 n 26.

Comment: so you need to index variants, search for it between two dates, than just group result of search by product using `@variants.group_by(&:product)` and render products from this array of hashes (`@variants.group_by(&:product).keys`) in any way you want...

Answer (score 0):

Index each model, and return the variant/product you need from SOLR. If you're using Spree by the way, there's a gem for integrating w/ sunspot and spree. I just forked it: https://github.com/banane/spree_sunspot_search